# What's the lowest tech level needed to create plastics?

Tags: magic

I'm thinking of doing a modern(ish) take on the world of Athas from D&D's Dark Sun campaign setting but seeing how far we can push the tech level without metals.  Could that society (let's ignore the magic and psionics for the moment) create plastics?  What about fiberglass?  Any other advanced materials?  We've got almost no metals and the water is also scarce.

Comment: As an alternative to plastics, you could consider ceramics which can be very durable when made well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no hard science tag, I'll go with an educated guess.

**No.**

And you are entirely right in using the word "society" instead of "level of technology" or something similar in the question. Plastics is by its nature a material of mass production. While various plastics probably could be manufactured by much lower technology level they do not really make sense without mass production. In our world that meant industrialization, but I'd believe plastics with renaissance level of economy, if lack of other materials forced the development.

It is doubtful a resource constrained society like "Dark Sun" could reach renaissance economy, though.

As an example of the difference. In medieval times walls were made of stone, because natural stone and stone scavenged from ancient masonry was more than sufficient for the need. During renaissance people started mass producing bricks to meet the needs of an expanding economy supplied by advances in food production.

IMHO, Dark Sun is very much in the medieval mode. Economy is smaller than it used to be in the past. The society is stagnant and surrounded by the ruins of the glorious past. It is difficult to see where an expansion of agricultural production capable of producing an expansion of economy that created a need for mass produced materials would come from.

Obviously, this all depends on how far from Dark Sun you want to take your setting. Personally, since the wastelands by my memory seem to be filled by weird psionic monsters I'd go Monster Hunter route and use materials scavenged from hunted monsters instead of plastics. But that "modernish" aspect you mentioned... Overall, I am still saying **no** since I find it too hard to believe you can expand the economy enough for plastics to make sense, while retaining the flavor of Dark Sun. Would be ecstatic to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I do plan on taking it pretty far from traditional D&D, only because my gaming group are an insane bunch of problem-solvers, forever trying to apply real-world science and engineering knowledge to pseudo-medieval worlds.

Comment: I don't know "Dark Sun" (or D&D in general), but since you speak of "ruins of the glorious past", couldn't that glorious past have been a modern world with lots of plastics around that could be scavenged? I mean, looking around me it's hard to find a view that doesn't contain any plastics item, and plastic is well known for its longevity. And reusing existing plastics should be much easier than producing new.

Comment: @celtschk Sure, some plastics are reusable. But it wouldn't be that different from using metals in flavor?

Answer (score 2):

[Rubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_rubber) is certainly a possibility, since it can be made directly from a tree sap.

[epoxy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy) appear to be made completely out of organic elements.

Many plastics are made from petroleum products, however, the first product considered plastic was made in 1856 and that would be during the industrial revolution.  [Vulcanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcanization) appears to be one of the precursors to making plastics.

One of the expectations I would see, is that instead of metallurgy and smithing, that chemistry would become a more common study.  Instead of hammering out a sword to kill someone, they would find other ways, maybe poisons and many happy accidents might ensue.  Of course with magic in the mix you never know what might happen.

Comment: I'm not sure that "trees" are a terribly popular concept on Athas. Last I heard, their arcane casters killed most of them off.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that in the absence of metal tools, a lot more attention would be paid to natural materials, that here on earth were variously made redundant, passed over, or developed only for art's sake rather than everyday utility. Here are some examples that I know of.

It's a remarkable fact that before Harrison  devoted much his life to developing a marine chronometer, he was a provincial maker of large clocks of the sort installed in church towers and atop prestigious buildings. He made them mostly out of wood. The bearings were lignum vitae, a wood naturally impregnated with a non-setting oil. Certainly there were metal components, but (probably) they weren't essential: things like screws to hold the wood together. At least one of these clocks is still working and still keeping good time, on those original bearings made of a very special wood.

Or take a look in a good museum at late stone age artifacts. Prior to the arrival of metal, working stone was a highly developed technology. Nobody today could reproduce tools that fine made from flint without using any higher technology product. The technology was lost, once superceded by a better one. And it's interesting to note that the sharpest blade available today for use in preparing sections for microscopy, is not any sort of metal razor blade. It's broken glass, or diamond for long life. Agate (high-grade flint) was once popular. Look up "ultramicrotomy".

The Romans once sent an army into Germany, across the Rhine. They build a wooden bridge across this major river in a couple of months. There are Roman buildings still in use today. Wood and brick will get you a long way.

Go to Hong Kong and admire the scaffolding used there. It's not steel poles. It's giant bamboo, lashed together with leather thongs. The local builders have yet to be convinced of the merits of steel poles.

Consider glass. Prior to a takeover, the UK had a world-leading glassmaker called Pilkington, which ran a superb corporate image advert on TV. A man was knocking a nail into a plank of wood with a claw hammer made of glass. And at the end of the ad, the nail had bent over, and the glass claw removed it. Why can't you buy a glass hammer in the shops? Because steel ones are cheaper in our world, and they are less prone to shattering when used carelessly. But if steel cost a thousand times more than glass?

I'm sure that there are lots of other examples of non-metallic technologies that aren't mainstream to be found in our modern world and in its museums. Whether the world might have found them without metal scaffolding (in the metaphorical sense), I can't say. I have great respect for human ingenuity. I suspect we would have done.

I wonder what a world that could make gunpowder, but not canons or rifles, might be like? History would read very differently.

You mention fiberglass. You might today experiment with fiberglass and linseed oil or tung oil. I suspect it would be almost as good as epoxy, but with an inconveniently long time to harden (months?). I now wonder if our mediaevals made fiberglass-equivalent things out of flax fiber bonded with linseed oil?  I've never heard of it, but they certainly knew of both. Flax is very, very strong.  Hemp (ship's ropes until polypropylene) is coarser but almost as good. BTW take care if you experiment, cloth impregnated with these sorts of oils has been known (rarely) to spontaneously ignite.

One last thought. Prior to the industrial revolution, the energy of a fire was used very inefficiently. One factor in the fall of Rome may well have been running out of trees to burn. Steam engines, and then internal combustion engines, were huge gains, but is there any way to control steam without metal boilers and cylinders? And could a world with expensive metals ever skip past steam to hydro-electricity? (water wheel, yes. A Michael Faraday, yes. But convincing someone to scale a toy up to a serious generator ...? )

Answer (score 1):

I just re-read *Tatja Grimm's World*, three novelettes from the great Vernor Vinge.  They have a metal-poor planet, where iron is measured in ounces and used for experiments and critical parts like bearings in the most advanced projects.  Basically it is as expensive and rare as gold is to us.

They have no concept of electricity, but have composites like fiberglass and plastic as well as wood.  They have petroleum available, but don't seem to be refining it except as cutting-edge revolutionary industry.

They might be working with and modifying natrual materials.   Pre-historic people were found to use bows made with composite materials!  In one case I recall, wood carefully cut with the heartwood and sapwood on different edges of a piece; in another, a bow made with horn cut into thin tiles and bonded together to form a laminate, as one side, and something completely different for the other side.

Shellac is made from a bug, as is silk.  Ancient people cultivated silkworms and never invented nylon.

Another thought along these lines is to look at gelatin.  Did anyone “invent” the process of producing gelatin from collagen?  No, it just sort of oozed out of dinner and was found to make a sticky mess.  People noticed the properties of materials that were *natural* and those that were *already occurring* as byproducts or happenstance, and remembered that as a catalog for when material with some specific properties were needed.

People figured out sour dough bread, beer, cheese, quicklime, and many other things.

So why not

- have some other specific biological materials available.  After all, silk etc. would seem pretty amazing if you had never heard of it before!  Plants, animals, and fungi might have secretions or parts that are similar in nature in providing a general material.  Look at different critters, like birds making nests from their spit, termites making mounds, etc.
- discover how to use natural materials as feedstock for more advanced materials, like vulcanization or like gelatin.  Especially if it is a modification of a natural material, or a byproduct of something eatable.

"plastic" refers more to the ease of molding and handling of un-molded pellets, not to the fact that it's far from biological in nature.  The plastics we use are really organic polymers, that just happen to be different from anything living things have made before.   The stuff that makes wood strong was novel once, and the reason we have coal is because it was fifty million years before fungi evolved to break it down.  In its day trees were like the styrofoam cups of today—they just pile up and don't rot away completely.

Now, biology probably won't come up with the exact same properties we find useful for thermoplastic, specifically the low melting point.  But a natural material might be *refined* into something like a plastic, just as gelatin is made from collagen simply by steaming it.

One of the ancient wonders of the world was a statue clad in ivory.  The small pieces were made soft and fused together.  It's pretty close to a plastic...  so what if horn or hair or feathers or bug exoskelletons could be *processed* in a matter no harder than making wine or cheese, into a material that is like wax but with a higher temperature of softening/melting?

Actually, just what is beeswax?!
How about an animal that makes something like wax, if not bees like we have, that can be modified by cooking it or mixing with something else... just as **soap** changes the base material.  Make the wax have a higher working temperature by further polymerizing it, catalyzing it, or some-such.  It's very plausible if you use techniques that people do in fact use for other things.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know the Dark Sun setting well, I'm going to take this from material point of view. Basically, what is possible without metals, advanced chemistry, and a petroleum industry? All of the below can or have been done with late 19th or early 20th century technology.

**Non-petroleum Plastics and Resins**

- [Natural rubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_rubber) and other tree gums.
- Artificial [latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latex) made from plant-derived [Styrene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Styrene).
- [Shellac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellac) (from bugs and trees).
- Animal horn.
- [Celluloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celluloid#History), starch treated with nitric acid and camphor (which comes from the [camphor tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamomum_camphora)).
- [Nylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon#Chemistry), there's so many different ways to make it you can probably make at least one work.

**Fiberglass**

Absolutely. Glass wool can be made [using compressed air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiberglass#History) or [extruded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiberglass#Production). When combined with a resin you get fiberglass.

**[Asbestos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asbestos#History_of_use)**

It is, surprisingly, naturally occurring and has been in use for over 4000 years.

**[Concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete)**

It has been in use for thousands of years. You might not think of it as an "advanced" material, but it is still our preferred building material. It has a high compressive strength, doesn't change size much with changes of temperature, won't rot, won't rust, won't burn, won't corrode from salt water, can be poured into many shapes, and can be made to last thousands of years.

**[Graphite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite) and [Silicon Carbide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_carbide)**

Silica sand and carbon [at very high temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acheson_process) produce graphite and silicon carbide.